# joomla 2.5 query select from one table insert into another

Tags: mysql, joomla

Using a joomla plugin I am trying to grab some user info from the '#__users' table and insert that info into another table '#__new_table' when the user is created.

The code is as follows

```
function onUserAfterSave( $user, $isnew, $success, $msg ) {
    if ($isnew && $success) {
      $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
      $db->setQuery( 'INSERT INTO #__new_table (user_id) VALUES ('.$user['id'].')' );
      $db->query();
    }
  }
```

The above works and the 'id' is copied over to the new table and is showing in the 'user_id' row. If I try the following however:

```
function onUserAfterSave( $user, $isnew, $success, $msg ) {
    if ($isnew && $success) {
      $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
      $db->setQuery( 'INSERT INTO #__new_table (name) VALUES ('.$user['username'].')' );
      $db->query();
    }
  }
```

Then this does not work even though the fields 'name' and 'username' exist in both tables.

Is there a better way to write this function for joomla 2.5. Also in the above examples I am just grabbing one value at a time. If I was trying to grab a few values at once from '#__users' to insert into a few fields in '#__new_table'.. how would I change the above function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `quote` username value.

```
function onUserAfterSave( $user, $isnew, $success, $msg ) {
    if ($isnew && $success) {
      $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
      $db->setQuery( 'INSERT INTO #__new_table (name) VALUES ('.$db->quote($user['username']).')' );
      $db->query();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to debug this problem is to print the query in the second example and paste it in phpMyAdmin and see what kind of error it will throw. My guess is that the id field in the second table cannot be null, but you are not adding it in the second example.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on debugging but the solution Irfan gave worked. Really like your informative joomla site btw!